# Django how to send data to django dispatcher url with AJAX?

Tags: python, django, ajax

so i was trying to send category to django url (that takes category when visited through url) with ajax in [this website](https://imao.herokuapp.com/jokes/1/), but i am getting this error which i don't seem to understand. Please help!

***urls.py***

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('category/<str:category>', views.getcategory, name = 'get_category'),
]
```

***views.py:***

```
def get_category(request, category=None):
    
    #To get category if requested via AJAX
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "GET":
        
        category = request.GET.get("last_joke_id", category)
    
    if category!=None:
        return HttpResponse('\n Received via Json. \n')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('\n Received via URL. \n')
```

***index.html:***

```
<script>
function send_category(category){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    *url:"{% url 'get_category' %}"*, /*Error in this line*/
    data: {'category':category},
    success: function(response) {
      console.log("\n\nCategory data Successfully recived.\n");
      console.log( response );
      //displayJokes(response);
    
    }, error: function (response) {
         console.log('\n\n error in retriving category data:');
         console.log(response);
         //return 'her';
       }
    
  })
}
</script>
```

***Error Message:***

`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'get_category' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['jokes/category/(?P[^/]+)$']`

Answer (score 0):

It means that `category` is required parameter in your route, so you may fix that if you change your route and view function, like that:

urls.py

```
path('category/', views.getcategory, name = 'get_category'),
```

views.py

```
def getcategory(request):
    category = request.GET.get("category")

    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "GET":
        category = request.GET.get("last_joke_id", category)

    if category!=None:
        return HttpResponse('\n Received via Json. \n')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('\n Received via URL. \n')
```

Or you may create two routes, with and without parameters:

```
path('category/', views.getcategory, name = 'get_category_default'),
path('category/<str:category>', views.getcategory, name = 'get_category'),
```

Then you need to set default value in your function:

```
def get_category(request, category=None):
    ...
```

And Finally you need to replace your `get_category` route to `get_category_default` in your js code

Comment: wow that worked and .......  is there a way around without changing url-pattern because same concept is working fine with <int:> in urlpattern like:   path('<int:joke_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote')

Comment: If you expect that Ajax make url like 'category/your-category-name' so it won't do that, because all params which passed into `data` option will be a "GET" of your url

Comment: and not even just call the function?

Comment: you may create two routes with params and without which will use same function which has category param with default value

Comment: I have completed my answer